# ActiveRelation Query is empty in Rails System Test, but works interactive

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Works in interactive session, but fails in Rails System test:

Using byebug, this one unexpectedly returns empty in show view

```
@item.children.where(done: false)
```

If I skip the ActiveRelation, like this, I see the object correctly

```
@item.children

#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Item id: 980190964, title: "my item", done: false
```

This one unexpectedly returns 1 record

```
@item.children.where.not(done:false)
```

Setup (works well)

```
  setup do
    @user = users(:one)
    visit login_url
    fill_in "Email", with: @user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: 'secret'
    click_on "Login"    
  end
```

The test (works well, but item will not display!)

```
  test "create one entry" do
    visit item_url(@user.top_item)
    fill_in('item[title]', with: 'my item')
    find_field('item[title]').native.send_key(:enter)    
    visit current_path
    assert_selector "h5", text: "parentObject", match: :one
  end
```

Part of show action:

```
@children = @item.children
@newItem = current_user.items.new
```

Part of show view:

```
<% @children.where(done: false).each do |item| %>
```

Even the @children attribute is empty. Reload does not make any difference.

Comment: You are going to have to provide a bit more detail. What does the test look like including the set up

Comment: I'm guessing you're using eager loading of children, so when you call @item.children in your test you're seeing cached versions of the children (from before whatever actions you've done to the page) and not that actual records from the DB - whereas by adding the `where` clause you're triggering a reload from the DB.  If you do `@item.reload.children` you'll probably see the data in the DB actually has done: true.

Comment: Added some detail. Reload has been tried, `@item.reload`, `@item.children.reload`, but no difference. The Done: false attribute will never change during test. Its always false. yes, could be some caching issue...

Comment: Observation: `@item.children.where(type:nil)` works, and so do `@item.children.where(title:"my item")` . Seems like the problem is related to detecting "true/false". Another true/false attribute does not work either. But strangely - all this works fine except in tests. Using Sqlite3.

Comment: @folium: "using sqlite3" - only for test? Or for everything?

Comment: No production yet... so sqlite3 only for now.

Comment: I would recommend always using Postgres (or mysql if you want) for both development and production, makes your life much easier.

Comment: Thank you @Eyeslandic. I have now switched db to one thats production ready. Been happy with sqlite3 - so easy to take backups / version control ++, but now that I switched I see your point more clearly. There were a few challenges, a gem stopped working, different column widths, column types... and now I gained some speed as well. More prod ready, and it feels good :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked when I set the below setting to false. I looked at the schema directly in sqlite3 and default for 'done' field is 'false' not '0'. But why then so smooth in development and not test? Maybe some conflict with the yaml files still using 'false'. So I will stick with the deprecated setting for a while, until I understand the implications fully, and can do a proper migration later.

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.sqlite3.represent_boolean_as_integer = false
```

My reason for trying true:

DEPRECATION WARNING: Leaving `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter.represent_boolean_as_integer`
set to false is deprecated. SQLite databases have used 't' and 'f' to serialize
boolean values and must have old data converted to 1 and 0 (its native boolean
serialization) before setting this flag to true. Conversion can be accomplished
by setting up a rake task which runs

```
ExampleModel.where("boolean_column = 't'").update_all(boolean_column: 1)
ExampleModel.where("boolean_column = 'f'").update_all(boolean_column: 0)
```

for all models and all boolean columns, after which the flag must be set to
true by adding the following to your application.rb file:

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.sqlite3.represent_boolean_as_integer = true
```